# Why I am not able to create array of class type in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I am making a car rental system and i want to inherit name from parent class.
Now I want to create an array of Cars which will contain 4 different cars. I don't want to give this array a simple data type because this car will have it's model number too! So I just want to go with abstract data type.
But when i write the class name with array (making it's data type of that of class) it says

```
[Error] field 'Cars' has incomplete type 'Car [4]'.
```

why and how to solve it?

I don't know what to do other than abstract data type.
Code is here:

```
class Vehicle{
   public:
    string name;
    int model;
    
};
class Car:public Vehicle{
    public:
        int seats;
        Car Cars[4];
        Car(){
    Cars[0].name = "Alto";
    Cars[1].name = "Mercedes";
    Cars[2].name = "Corolla";
    Cars[3].name = "Audi";
}
```

Comment: How do you expect a `Car` to contain 4 `Car`s inside itself?

Comment: You can create an array of cars just not inside of the `Car` class. Your car class represents one car, not four.

Comment: A new twist on "How do you fit 4 elephants into a car? ... 2 in the front 2 in the back."

Comment: Thankyou for replying.I want to create a collection of cars. That's why made an array naming Cars. Why would it not work?

Comment: If one car contains 4 cars, each of which contains 4 cars, each of which contains 4 cars, ... how many cars do you expect to end up with?

Comment: _Inside_ a car you are trying to fit 4 cars... each which will have 4 cars. Ad infinitum. To fix it, create your array _outside_ of the `Car` class, or make the array `static`.

Comment: _"Why would it not work ?"_ It's a logic issue. You're trying to define a `Car` based on... well... `Car` (which isn't defined yet since you are still on the way to define it). It is even worse, you're trying to tell that with 4 `Car`s (which is not defined yet), we can make 1 `Car`. It's a non-sense. What you can do instead is to make a `Car` hold a `Car*` member, which is another story.

Answer (score 6):

So I think the code you are looking for is something like this

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    string name;
    int model;
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    int seats;
};

int main()
{
    Car Cars[4];
    Cars[0].name = "Alto";
    Cars[1].name = "Mercedes";
    Cars[2].name = "Corolla";
    Cars[3].name = "Audi";
}
```

It's perfectly OK to create an array of `Car` but it's not legal to (and there is no reason to) create it inside of the `Car` class. Create the array in `main` (or somewhere) instead.